# $_GET variables disappear when mod_rewrite rewrites .html to .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite .html to .php.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

But, I'm having issues when using a $_GET in the URL. It works fine if requested URL is in this format: `index.php?a=f1`

BUT, if it rewrites it to `home.html?a=f1`, NOTHING.

Assuming it's just the browser stops reading after it hits the .html. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The reason is best explained in the documentation:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

Comment: This gives an Internal Server Error.

Comment: I removed the L flag and it's working.  If I leave it as [QSA, L] it gives the Internal Server Error.

Comment: There should be no white-space inside flags. `[QSA, L]` is bad, `[QSA,L]` is good.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `home.htm&a=f1`

the hidden url is: `index.php?p=home&a=f1`